# Is $gnu(n)<n$ always true for cubefree $n>1$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, gap, groups-enumeration

> Let $gnu(n)$ be the number of groups of order $n$. If $n$ is cubefree, (there is no prime $p$ with $p^3|n$), does the inequality $gnu(n)<n$ always hold for $n>1$ ?

According to GAP, upto $50,000$, this is the case. Since the maximal gnu I got was $3093$, I conjecture that the inequality holds for all cubefree $n$. Can this be proven ?

For squarfree $n>1$, it is known that $gnu(n)\le \phi(n)<n$.

Comment: I found [this](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0021869304006325/1-s2.0-S0021869304006325-main.pdf?_tid=78f75e32-a545-11e5-9826-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1450415530_9760be3d03482883ef451ddeb45226dc) reference which might be of some use, but on quick inspection doesn't seem to directly answer your question.